# ADMM difficulty in finding active inequality constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I have implemented a convex optimization algorithm based on the ADMM approach for quadratic programming of the form below:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^T Q x + px\\ \text{subject to} & Ax + b = 0\\ \text{    } & Dx + E <=0\end{array}$$

the problem is that when some of the inequalities become active in the optimal solution, ADMM get too slow and actually it can't find the active ones, I thought it might be caused by ill-scaled matrices and I used a preconditioning method from "An Operator Splitting Solver for Quadratic Programs" article, but nothing changed and  it still cannot find active inequalities. I have used Active-Set method to polish the solution obtained by the ADMM method, but as the active set is not known after running the ADMM algorithm it takes too many iterations to reach the optimal solution, Do you know any method other than the Active-Set method for polishing the solution?

Comment: Have you spent much time tuning the ADMM step size? That can make a big difference. For diagnosing the problem it would be useful to see a plot of the residuals $\|Ax^k + b\|$ and $\sum(\max(Dx^k + E,0))$ versus iteration number.

Comment: @littleO Actually, I once used a method to calculate the step size it was something related to the eigenvalues of matrices, but it wasn't helpful that much so I dropped it.

Comment: For debugging, you could try solving a version of the problem that uses artificially constructed matrices that are well conditioned. You can see if that works at least.

Comment: @littleO I create my test cases by using  matrices with random elements and it works for some range of elements values, but when I change the range of values it gets inaccurate.

Comment: @littleO Do you know any method that can be used for polishing the solution obtained by ADMM? because it can obtain the solution with modest accuracy.

Comment: How large is the problem? (How many columns does $Q$ have?) Have you considered using an interior point method?

Comment: @littleO I'm going to use it for large problems, for example it can be of order of several thousands.and I have used interior point methods but the problem is that interior point method cannot be warm-started by the solution obtained by ADMM, so it is of no avail, I need some algorithm that can reach the optimal point with high accuracy while warm starting with the solution of ADMM, and this solution is so close to the optimal point.

Comment: If $Q$ has a few thousand columns, it may be that abandoning ADMM entirely and just using an interior point method is the best way to go. Interior point methods are great, it's just that some problems are so large that we can't use them. By the way, it still wasn't clear to me if you have spent much time manually tuning the ADMM step size. That can make a huge difference. (You mentioned a heuristic based on eigenvalues, but I'm not surprised that the heuristic performed poorly.)

Comment: @littleO actually I have been thinking that tunning step size may cost a lot, and I remember that in some articles it was mentioned that it'd better to use heuristic method to find a good step size so I didn't pay much attention to it.Would you please recemmond an article or something on this issue?

Comment: It's true that tuning the step size is very laborious, but once it's tuned you might hope that the same step size will work for similar problems in the same application. Is this project for industry or for academia?  In academic papers it's not uncommon to have step sizes be tuned manually via "grad student descent". If the ADMM step size is not tuned correctly, then ADMM will often converge so slowly that it essentially fails. In an industrial application where you need the algorithm to work robustly, the need to tune the step size might be a deal breaker.

Comment: You might try out the POGS implementation of ADMM, which uses an adaptive step size strategy that I've found to work well in my experiments. The POGS code is available online.